# Access Table API from a process function in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new with Flink and I am trying to learn.
I am trying to use the Table API within a process function after I aggregate some row so that I can do and insert based on specific criteria. The goal is to process a tuple with table_name and list of rows to insert.

Is that an acceptable pattern? This is kind of an example

```
groupped.process(new ProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, List<JsonObject>>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(Tuple2<String, List<JsonObject>> input,
                                       ProcessFunction<Tuple2<String, List<JsonObject>>, Object>.Context context,
                                       Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {

                String table = input.f0;
                List<JsonObject> jsonrows = input.f1;

                TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(EnvironmentSettings.inBatchMode());

                PROCESS LOGIC HERE
                ....


            }
    }
```

Comment: The TableEnvironment definition should be created once when bootstrapping the Flink application. Your code example would attempt to create one for each invocation of the ProcessFunction, which is not what you want (I don't think this will work either, as TableEnvironment is probably not Serializable). Instead, if you want to operate on a Table as a stream, you can call `table.toDataStream` to convert it to a `DataStream[Row]` and then apply your ProcessFunction. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/ for more.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases it does make sense to combine the datastream and table APIs, but it needs to be done in a different way.

With both of these APIs, what you're doing with the API is building up a job graph, which is a description of the data processing pipeline that will be executed by Flink. Each stage, or task, in that graph is executed by a specific operator (e.g., in the case of a ProcessFunction that's done by the process operator). Some of these operators are implemented in Flink by the datastream API, and others by the table API. You can decide to write parts of your job with the datastream API, and other parts with the table API, but you can't embed these APIs inside each other.

What your process function can do is transform each list it receives into a bunch of separate events. You could also do this with a flatmap. You can then turn this datastream into a table, and insert it into some data store using a table connector.

I have [a complete example project](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-mobile-data-usage) that does this sort of thing, and the Flink documentation has [more examples showing how to integrate these two APIs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/).